# Can't upload a ppt file to Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, file-upload, powerpoint

I'm trying to upload a ppt file to Amazon S3 in the AWS Console.

I thought it would be feasible, because I've uploaded a pdf file previously and it went well.

The error msg said:

> Failed to execute 'readAsArrayBuffer' on 'FileReaderSync': The requested file could not be read, typically due to permission problems that have occurred after a reference to a file was acquired.

Can I upload a ppt file to Amazon S3?

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be with your PPT file. There is no issue uploading and storing PPT files in an Amazon S3 bucket. You can upload it through the Amazon S3 Console or by using the various Amazon S3 SDKs.

[image]

Comment: The issue to this was indeed on PPT file. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was that the file was still being modified by another process.